# SyncAdapters.requestSync and Android SyncManager

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I'm trying to understand the workings of SyncAdapters. I looked at the code for when we receive a GCM notification from a broadcast receiver. We want to force the SyncAdapter to sync immediately by calling requestSync as the GCM is telling my app that there is new data available to fetch.

I got the code below from this link: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/handling-offline-capability-and-data-sync-in-an-android-app-part-2

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = GcmBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
    public GcmBroadcastReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(gcm.getMessageType(intent)) &&
                intent.getExtras().containsKey("com.example.restaurant.SYNC_REQ")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "GCM sync notification! Requesting DB sync for server dbversion " + intent.getStringExtra("dbversion"));
            ContentResolver.requestSync(new Account("dummyaccount", "com.example.restaurant"),
                    RestaurantContentProvider.AUTHORITY, Bundle.EMPTY);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I read about SyncAdapters from here: http://naked-code.blogspot.com/2011/05/revenge-of-syncadapter-synchronizing.html) and they mentioned that:

> a SyncAdapter is just a service that is started by the sync manager,
>   which in turn maintains a queue of SyncAdapters.

If my phone has a couple of different SyncAdapters related to different apps (Facebook, Twitter etc.) and they all have items they need to sync (for example, new posts on Facebook or Twitter), it looks like all these SyncAdapters would be put into a queue waiting till the SyncManager gives the go-ahead to sync all these SyncAdapters.

If my app calls the command to sync now - ContentResolver.requestSync(), does that mean that all the other apps (Facebook, Twitter etc) also gets sync-ed at the same time?

I looked at the definition of requestSync method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#requestSync(android.accounts.Account, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)

**public static void requestSync (Account account, String authority,
Bundle extras)**

> Start an asynchronous sync operation. If you want to
>   monitor the progress of the sync you may register a SyncObserver.

**public static void requestSync (SyncRequest request)**

> **Register a sync with the SyncManager**. These requests are built using
>   the SyncRequest.Builder.

Is the requestSync calling the SyncManager to sync all its syncAdapters?

Answer (score 0):

If you use code to explicitly force a syncadapter to run, all accounts will sync.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
//deprecated in API level 5
//bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_FORCE, true);
bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
ContentResolver.requestSync(null, MyContentProvider.getAuthority(), bundle);
```

SyncAdapters are made to sync automatically but not immediately. In other words, it would be hard to estimate exact time when sync adapter will run unless you force it to. 
[See developer docs on this](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html#RunOnDemand)

Comment: But will the accounts (as in the ones from the Account class) sync or will all apps (Facebook, Twitter) sync?

Comment: Due to use of "SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL" all device accounts will we sync immediately, even if background data are disabled (thanks to "SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL")! So yes, other apps will also sync. Any app that uses SyncAdapters must use accounts and will therefore sync.

Comment: By the way, SYNC_EXTRAS_FORCE is deprecated in API level 5. Use SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL instead.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, be sure to read the [guide for creating a SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) and [how to run one](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html).

Note that a `SyncAdapter` syncs data for a single `ContentProvider`, identified by an authority string.  In many of the `ContentResolver` methods related to requesting or cancelling the running of a SyncAdapter, for example [requestSync()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#requestSync(android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)), you will see a String parameter for authority.  That identifies the ContentProvider the request applies to.

You asked:

> If my app calls the command to sync now -
>   ContentResolver.requestSync(), does that mean that all the other apps
>   (Facebook, Twitter etc) also gets sync-ed at the same time?

No. Your sync request will contain the authority string for your ContentProvider, for example: "com.example.myprovider". You are requesting the sync of only that specific provider using the scheduling options you specify (now, periodic, data changed, network message).

It's possible, depending on the options you use when you request sync, that your adapter will run at the same time as the adapters for other apps. But that is not under your control, it is just the consequence of the system batching syncs to minimize battery drain and metered data usage. If another app has requested a one-per-day periodic, and you request your adapter sync immediately (soon), your adapter running does not affect the once-per-day scheduling of the other adapter.

> Is the requestSync calling the SyncManager to sync all its
>   syncAdapters?

No, just yours--the one you specify with the authority parameter. I haven't verified it by experiment, but I doubt very much that the system would allow an app to request or cancel the syncing of ContentProviders owned by other apps.  Imagine the havoc if a rogue app were allowed to control the running of other apps adapters.

Regarding accounts: My understanding is that the Account information is provided to the SyncAdapter to allow it to sign into the server being syncd with.